# How to use step filters for java ee application

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I want to use step filters in my jboss app. I found several articles how to use it (eg. http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-usestepfilters.htm) but it doesn't work for my project (jsf project deployed on jboss server). Are step filters work only for Java SE applications?

I tried to use step filters in this way:

1. Go to `Window->Preferences->Java->Debug->Step Filtering`.
2. Add package which you are interested in, eg. `com.company.*`.
3. Apply changes.
4. Enable `Use step filters` in Debug window.
5. Debug application and check if Debug window shows only `com.company.*` packages.

Comment: No, its all the same - Java. You are doing something wrong, but it will be impossible to say what until you can show what you're doing and what result you're getting.

Comment: Check the debug ports are open on your JBoss server.  You should even be able to remotely debug live JBoss servers if the ports are open outside of your IDE.